# Publish an output from MATLAB including a PDF file opened by OPEN command

Tags: matlab, pdf, file-io, output, publish

I have a code in MATLAB that calculates some values, prints graphs, and opens a documentation PDF.

`Publish` is able to capture the `disp` output and graphs easily.  However, the PDF file opened from the function file using `open('My.pdf')` is not captured by the publisher.

The publisher uses html format.  Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No -- the PDF is opened in a separate application, and Matlab won't include it in the publishing operation.

As a kludge you could make a screenshot yourself and then display it using `imread` and `image`.